# NSMutable objects: removeAllObjects vs. containsObject speed

Tags: ios, optimization

Disclaimer: I'm relatively new to iOS development. I'm using ARC for this project.

I'd like to know which of these operations is faster and why?

```
if([selectedIndexes containsObject:indexPath]) {
    [selectedIndexes removeAllObjects];
    for(int i=0; i<self.options.count; i++) {
        [selectedIndexes addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];   
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath;
if([selectedIndexes containsObject:indexPath]) {
    for(int i=0; i<self.options.count; i++) {
        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
        if(![selectedIndexes containsObject:indexPath])
            [selectedIndexes addObject:indexPath];
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

The question is really that whether doing removeAllObjecs and then adding things back would work faster or having to check if the item is already not there, add it to the set?

Comment: couldn't you just use [NSMutableIndexSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: Is this really THE time critical part of your app? If not I would leave it to the compiler to produce a reasonable code.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you explain about the role of self.options in your code?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner Not really. I'm just trying to understand which of these would work faster.

Comment: @Anupdas self.options is a NSArray containing string values. (i.e. Red, Blue, Green, etc.) in a settings view controller. The selectedIndexes would be passed to the delegate, containing the selected options indexes.

Comment: Is `selectedIndexes` an array or a set?

Comment: Write the code in the way that most clearly and directly expresses your intent.  Then, **if the profiler says it's too slow,** worry about finding a faster way.

Answer (score 1):

Lets analyse this (the `if` that wrap the loop is the same so I'll ignore it):

Option 1:
`-removeAllObjects`: all objects are removed from the array, each is released once ==> N operations at the minimum ==> O(N)
The loop makes N iterations each of which:
*    Create an `NSIndexPath` ==> O(1)
*    Add the index path to the end of the array ==> O(1)
==> O(N) + O(N) + N*O(1) + N*O(1) = 2O(N) + 2*N*O(1) = 4O(N) = O(N)

Option 2:
The loop makes N iterations each of which:
*    Create an `NSIndexPath` ==> O(1)
*    Verify existence in the array ==> O(N) (an array must assume that it may contain duplicates)
*    The `if` statement will also have its toll as it will be asked N times, and will mess the branch predication of the loop.
**        The addition in the loop is a probabilistic matter (lets ignore it for now)
==> N*(O(1) + O(N) + O(1)) = N*O(N) + 2*N*O(1) = O(N^2)

==> Flat analysis would suggest that the first option is better.

If you were to use a `NSMutableIndexSet` your code would look like this for both options:

```
//Not tested
//Assume that selectedIndexes is a NSMutableIndexSet
if ([selectedIndexes containsIndex:indexPath.row]) {
    if (self.options.count) {//This could probably be optimised depend on your goal
        [selectedIndexes addIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0,self.options.count-1)];
    } else {
        [selectedIndexes removeAllIndexes];
    }
}
```

==> The worst case complexity here would probably be O(N)

**Please feel free to correct any wrong assumptions or calculations**